# How can I create pre-configured apps with angular-cli?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

We create new Angular 4 apps all the time.
Virtually all of them need OAuth components and other shared services.

Instead of adding those components and services manually each time, I'm wondering if there's a way to pre-configure a skeleton app based on the standard angular-cli app structure but with our items already added in?

Comment: You could use http://yeoman.io/ and make your own generator ?

Comment: Thanks for that, WilomGfx. I didn't know yeoman. I do have concerns, tho, about privacy. Some of our code I wouldn't want to share publicly.

Comment: You dont have to upload them to yeoman repo. Keep them internally.

Comment: If you use git , you can host them in your repository and add to package.json . Since it's on your repository it's private and only those with permissions can use it .